# How to remove HTTPService from log target

Tags: apache-flex, httpservice

I'm using HTTPService in my app and I added a logging target and now I'm getting logging info from the HTTPService.

For example, I'm getting this message, "Processing HTTPService response message" and "Decoding HTTPService response".

Is there a way to turn this off or on (when I'm not using TraceTarget) or filter these calls out?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I not sure if you done this already but you can play with the filters and levels of log you want to manage.

```
 var logTarget:TraceTarget = new TraceTarget();
      logTarget.filters=["mx.rpc.*","mx.messaging.*"];
      logTarget.level = LogEventLevel.ALL;
      Log.addTarget(logTarget);
```

Comment: This filters everything but information from those two classes.

Comment: It is clear that only filters what these two classes, is an example of how to filter messages.